# Unable to understand the controller functionality in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependencies

I am new to Angular JS.I am trying to gain some in depth knowledge in it by understanding the controller functionality.

I came across the following code snippets.

```
var App = angular.module('clientApp', ['ngResource', 'App.filters']);
 App.controller('ClientCtrl', ['$scope',function ($scope) {

   }]);
```

What  significant difference does it make if i write :

```
 var App = angular.module('clientApp', ['ngResource', 'App.filters']);
 App.controller('ClientCtrl', function ($scope) {

   });
```

My Understanding:
I do understand that something written in the square brackets is dependency for that particular module or controller.However,I couldnot understand the reason for writing

```
          "['$scope',function($scope)"
```

instead of

```
   App.controller(controllername,function($scope){

   });
```

Any help wouls be highly appreciated!

Comment: you don't have to do that, and in fact i think it makes angular code a lot harder to scan/read. i don't mind libs and other black boxes using it (for min), but i don't think the (hopefully) tiny application files will slow down startup because they aren't minified...

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

It enables AngularJS code to be minified. AngularJS uses parameter names to inject the values to your controller function. In JavaScript minification process, these parameters are renamed to shorter strings. By telling which parameters are injected to the function with a string array, AngularJS can still inject the right values when the parameters are renamed.

Answer (score 1):

It should actually be written like this according to the [John Papa Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md):

First we create and name a `module` called '`app`'. We also create a `controller` called '`SomeController`'.

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('SomeController', SomeController);
```

Now we inject the dependencies we require into the controller

```
SomeController.$inject = ['dataservice', 'logger'];
```

Now we create the corresposnding function for the controller. Notice how the dependencies are included?

```
function SomeController(dataservice, logger) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.avengers = [];

    activate();

    function activate() {
        return getAvengers().then(function() {
            logger.info('Activated Avengers View');
        });
    }

    function getAvengers() {
        return dataservice.getAvengers()
            .then(function(data) {
                vm.avengers = data;
                return vm.avengers;
            });
    }
}
```